# Which is correct "Don’t make noise" vs "Don’t make a noise"

Tags: expressions

> 1. Don’t make noise. Students are taking the exams
> 2. Don’t make a noise. Students are taking the exams

I think the second one is correct.

Comment: Yes, the second is correct. I can't give any logical explanation, since the reference is to noisy behaviour in general rather than a single sound, but that is the idiomatic usage.

Comment: Either is correct.  I would prefer the first in the given context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, a more common usage would be, "Don't make any noise. The students are taking their exams."

"A" noise would be used in a more "firm" way, as in "If you make a single noise, I will send you out of the room!".

Comment: Salty, you were correct.  I have no idea why someone downvoted.

Comment: Cheers, no worries, I'm on holiday so among other reasons just killing time on this site :) I'm a native speaker/writer and lived in various countries so maybe I can comment on common usage.